# How to plot packets vs seconds using pcap file

Tags: pcap, tshark

Using tshark I tried to generate a dat file. The following is the command that I used to generate the fields using tshark:

```
$ C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireshark>tshark.exe -r "C:\swp-final-30.0.0.13.pcap"  -T
 fields -e frame.number -e frame.time  -e  eth.src -e eth.dst -e ip.src -e ip.ds
t -e ip.proto -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > C:\thirty.
dat

Tshark generates the output file in this format.
409     Jul 14, 2012 17:50:19.435836000 00:04:23:b7:3e:a3       00:04:23:b7:1a:0b       20.0.0.13       30.0.0.13       6
410     Jul 14, 2012 17:50:19.436084000 00:04:23:b7:3e:a3       00:04:23:b7:1a:0b       20.0.0.13       30.0.0.13       6
411     Jul 14, 2012 17:50:19.436110000 00:04:23:b7:1a:0b       00:04:23:b7:3e:a3       30.0.0.13       20.0.0.13       6
```

1. I want to plot a graph for the numbers packets per second.  How do I calculate the number of packets using the above mentioned data for specific flow?
2. How do generate a log for the specific flows matching `ip.dst== 30.0.0.13` from the large pcap file?

Answer (score 0):

you can start with time 0(time of first packet)
count the number of packets until time increase by one second

repeat the above step for each second and you will get no. of packets per second